# script for selecting a string from random letters

Tags: python, algorithm

My code allows you to guess the hidden string from the letters and numbers it consists of. But my code is not very efficient as it can generate the same strings. If I do a search for a string from the letters of the entire alphabet, then it will search for me a string until the morning. How can you foresee this moment?

```
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time
startTime = datetime.now()
password = 'qwerty'
letters = 'werqty'
searchPassword = ''
counter = 0
while searchPassword != password:
    searchPassword = ''
    for i in range(6):
        searchPassword += letters[random.randint(0, 5)]
    print(searchPassword)
    counter += 1
print(counter)
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Here are examples of three script runs:

```
#1
counter = 33895
time = 0:00:10.278330
```

```
#2
counter = 2214
time = 0:00:00.218893
```

```
#3
counter = 46308
time = 0:00:11.910321
```

In general, it all depends on the random.
The script can find the string both in 1 second and in 1 minute.
Any ideas how to make the algorithm faster?

Comment: Does the hidden string only consist of alphanumerics?

Comment: Don't print all candidates, just print the correct one after the loop.

Comment: The only optimization I can think of (other than not printing the candidates as Kelly said) would be to have some compound for loops that increment through the letters rather than randomly cycling through. Generally randomness isn't good in algorithms, with a few exceptions.

Comment: Also worth noting that no matter what, this is still an O(n!) algorithm, which is very bad, so you'll still have a rough time with longer "passwords".

Comment: @csjh I'd rather say O(n^n).

Comment: @csjh for example, if I even search for the string 'abcd', but from all the letters (26 letters), then it will be very long

Comment: @KellyBundy the time complexity of [bruteforce algorithm is O(n!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_without_repetitions). But if you are using [a randomized algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#Monte_Carlo_and_random_numbers) in average you will have a much better actual performance.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Kosmak Unclear why you're linking to "without repetitions". The OP's code suggests otherwise. If they wanted without, they would've used `random.sample` (or a diy-equivalent like they did instead of using `random.choices`).

Comment: @KellyBundy you are possibly right, but I believe it's rather a mistake in code than an actual attempt.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Kosmak What makes you believe the password can't have repetitions, though? I've probably created passwords on *hundreds* of sites and I think repetitions were *never* forbidden. Also, why would randomization have "much better actual performance"?

Comment: @KellyBundy you interpret the author's case as real, as for me, it is entirely synthetic. It seemed to me that the author's task was to study randomized algorithms, and therefore he used various symbols in the example.

Comment: @KellyBundy and if we are talking about the performance of the Monte-Carlo method, it's a vast subject. For me, the example of the [Miller-Rabin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) is representative to say that this approach is effective in practice.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Kosmak I'd need to familiarize myself with Miller-Rabin again to know for sure, but I'm not convinced we have an equivalent situation here. With random sampling you expect n! attempts and might take more than that, while with enumerating all possibilities you expect only n!/2 attempts and never need more than n!, no? Plus, generating strings randomly to takes more time for each string. How am I wrong?

Comment: @Yevgeniy Kosmak ... (continuing) I just modified your test, simple enumeration with itertools.permutations appears to be about 35 times faster than yours.

Comment: @KellyBundy you are totally correct at all points. Monte-Carlo method is suitable if we can achieve average-case complexity better than using brute-force solution.

Comment: @KellyBundy `itertools.permutations appears to be about 35 times faster than yours` indeed so. But if you use `9876543210` as a `password` and `0123456789` as a `letters`, the randomized solution might be better. As I said, it's synthetical cases.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Kosmak Yes, yes, I'm not totally against all kinds of randomization here. In fact I did randomize in my test, using `permutations(random.sample(letters, 6))`, partly in order to combat people thinking 9876543210 will be tested last :-)

Comment: What are you simulating? What are you able to verify for a given guess?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to implement a variation of [Monte-Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) on this task. The simplest way using Python is to use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```py
import random
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.now()
password = 'qwerty'
letters = 'werqty'
searchPassword = ''
counter = 0

while searchPassword != password:
    searchPassword = ''.join(random.sample(letters, 6))
    counter += 1
print(counter)
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

I'd tested its performance. On my laptop I've got ~7.3s for 1000 launches. Code for testing:

```py
import random
from datetime import datetime

password = 'qwerty'
letters = 'werqty'
searchPassword = ''
counter = 0

total_time = 0

for run in range(1000):
    startTime = datetime.now()
    while searchPassword != password:
        searchPassword = ''.join(random.sample(letters, 6))
        counter += 1
    searchPassword = ''
    total_time += (datetime.now() - startTime).total_seconds()

print(f"{total_time}")
```

My output:

```
7.202784999999992
```

Answer (score 1):

Random guess is not the best practice, if you don't have a dictionary to iterate through, brute forcing through all combinations in a random order is your best option.

```py
import random
from datetime import datetime
import time

from itertools import product

startTime = datetime.now()
password = 'qwerty'
letters = 'werqty'
searchPassword = ''
counter = 0

comb_list = list(product(letters, repeat=6))
random.shuffle(comb_list) 

guess = ''
for comb in comb_list:
    guess = ''.join(comb)
    if(guess == password):
        print("Found: ", guess)
        break;
    counter+=1;


print(counter)
print(datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Execute time

```
0:00:00.059003
```